# Can we rely on onStop() being called?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

Concerning Android's Activity lifecycle, I've seen it widely claimed (on SO and elsewhere) that persistent data should be saved in the onPause() method, because there is no guarantee that onStop() will be called, since the OS may need to kill the activity to reclaim its resources if system resources are running low.

However, in a book I'm reading, the opposite is stated:

> Practically speaking, the OS will not reclaim a visible (paused or
> resumed) > activity. **Activities are not marked as "killable" until
> onStop() is called and finishes executing.**
>
> [Talks about stashed
> state and activity record a bit]
>
> Note that your activity can pass into the stashed state without
> onDestroy() being called. **You can rely on onStop() and
> onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)  being called** (unless something has gone
> horribly wrong on the device) ... **Override onStop() to save any
> permanent data**, such as things the user  is editing, because your
> activity may be killed at any time after this method returns.
>
> *p70-71, Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide, 3rd Edition
> (emphasis mine)*

#### Multi-Part Question:

- Is this (possibility of an app being killed before onStop() is
  called) something that is no longer true in and is still being
  propagated, or is the book outright wrong?
- Is there some nuance to when or why an Activity might be killed that
  makes the answer "sometimes?"
- If the book is correct, why is that misconception so widely spread? (E.g. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166201/android-onsaveinstancestate-and-onpause), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777955/save-persistent-data-in-onpause-or-onstop), and [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395960/can-an-activity-be-killed-with-just-onpause?rq=1))

References to official documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit: Added links to other answers concerning onPause() vs onStop() guarantee

Answer (score 4):

This is an illustration of Activity lifecycle : 
[image]

According to the [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onPause),

> **onPause()** execution is **very brief**, and does not necessarily **afford
>   enough time to perform save operations**. For this reason, you should
>   not use **onPause()** to save application or user data, make network
>   calls, or execute database transactions; such work may not complete
>   before the method completes. Instead, you should perform **heavy-load**
>   shutdown operations during **onStop()**. For more information about
>   suitable operations to perform during onStop(), [see onStop()](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onstop).

There is a case when the app go from `onPause()` to `onCreate()` without `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`  is when another app with higher priority needs memory as you see the illustration.

Also, The activity could be destroyed without calling `onStart()`,
   `onStop()` when you call `finish()` method on `onCreate()` [see reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578708/android-scenario-where-ondestroy-is-called-without-onpause-or-onstop)